# How to restrict ship to specific countries for several products

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-address, zipcode

There are several products in my store that can only be shipped to the United States, UK, France, Germany, Canada. In addition to these products, other products can be shipped to all countries in the world.

How can I set restrictions on these products to allow only United States, UK, French, German and Canadian consumers to place orders?

thanks

Comment: you need to used magento event observer for this.

Comment: create new custom multi select attribute with all country, handle this attribute with your requirement using observer

Comment: Is there an extension that can do this?